# Align text in columns as a receipt in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to display different columns in the same position so it's more readable

```
orders = [
  (7306010, '06-01-2020', 'Lenovo V145 15.6" FHD Laptop AMD A9-9425, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Black', 'IntelliWorld', '£444.99', 1, 'Delivered'),
  (7224010, '24-12-2019', 'Samsung Galaxy M30s SIM Free Smartphone', 'DigiTec Limited', '£249.00', 4, 'Delivered'), 
  (7224010, '24-12-2019', 'Nikon Digital DSLR Camera Body (Black)', 'Orinoco UK', '£721.00', 1, 'Delivered'), 
  (7130010, '30-11-2019', 'Nintendo Switch', 'Orinoco UK', '£329.99', 6, 'Delivered'), (7102000, '02-11-2019', 'Huawei Y6 32GB 6.09 inch Smartphone', 'DigiTec Limited', '£107.50', 2, 'Delivered'), 
  (6731010, '31-07-2019', 'Numskull Multi-Format Pro Steering Wheel', 'Orinoco UK', '£69.99', 3, 'Delivered'), 
  (7304010, '04-01-2019', 'Canon DSLR Camera (Black)', 'Orinoco UK', '£249.00', 12, 'Delivered')]

print("Order ID\tOrder Date\t\tProduct Description\t\tSeller Name\t\tQuantity\t\tPrice")
for order in orders:
            order_id = order[0]
            order_date = order[1]
            prod_descrip = order[2]
            sel_name = order[3]
            quantity  = order[4]
            price= order[5]
            print("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t".format(order_id,order_date,prod_descrip,sel_name,quantity,price))
```

Here is my output:

```
Order ID    Order Date      Product Description     Seller Name     Quantity        Price
7306010     06-01-2020      Lenovo V145 15.6" FHD Laptop AMD A9-9425, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Black  IntelliWorld    £444.99 1
7224010     24-12-2019      Samsung Galaxy M30s SIM Free Smartphone DigiTec Limited £249.00 4
7224010     24-12-2019      Nikon Digital DSLR Camera Body (Black)  Orinoco UK  £721.00 1
7130010     30-11-2019      Nintendo Switch Orinoco UK  £329.99 6
7102000     02-11-2019      Huawei Y6 32GB 6.09 inch Smartphone DigiTec Limited £107.50 2
6731010     31-07-2019      Numskull Multi-Format Pro Steering Wheel    Orinoco UK  £69.99  3
7304010     04-01-2019      Canon DSLR Camera (Black)   Orinoco UK  £249.00 12
```

And Im trying to make it more like this [(CLICK)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lFqp.png)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Note you can simplify in `print("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t".format(*order[:-1]))` that flatten the list without the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the prettytable library for this one

https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable()

x.field_names = ["order_id", "order_date", "prod_descrip", "sel_name", "quantity", "price", "delivered?"]

x.add_rows(
    [
  (7306010, '06-01-2020', 'Lenovo V145 15.6" FHD Laptop AMD A9-9425, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Black', 'IntelliWorld', '£444.99', 1, 'Delivered'),
  (7224010, '24-12-2019', 'Samsung Galaxy M30s SIM Free Smartphone', 'DigiTec Limited', '£249.00', 4, 'Delivered'),
  (7224010, '24-12-2019', 'Nikon Digital DSLR Camera Body (Black)', 'Orinoco UK', '£721.00', 1, 'Delivered'),
  (7130010, '30-11-2019', 'Nintendo Switch', 'Orinoco UK', '£329.99', 6, 'Delivered'), (7102000, '02-11-2019', 'Huawei Y6 32GB 6.09 inch Smartphone', 'DigiTec Limited', '£107.50', 2, 'Delivered'),
  (6731010, '31-07-2019', 'Numskull Multi-Format Pro Steering Wheel', 'Orinoco UK', '£69.99', 3, 'Delivered'),
  (7304010, '04-01-2019', 'Canon DSLR Camera (Black)', 'Orinoco UK', '£249.00', 12, 'Delivered')
  ]
)

print(x)



Result:

└> $ python orders.py 
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| order_id | order_date |                             prod_descrip                            |     sel_name    |  price  | quantity | delivered? |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 7306010  | 06-01-2020 | Lenovo V145 15.6" FHD Laptop AMD A9-9425, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Black |   IntelliWorld  | £444.99 |    1     | Delivered  |
| 7224010  | 24-12-2019 |               Samsung Galaxy M30s SIM Free Smartphone               | DigiTec Limited | £249.00 |    4     | Delivered  |
| 7224010  | 24-12-2019 |                Nikon Digital DSLR Camera Body (Black)               |    Orinoco UK   | £721.00 |    1     | Delivered  |
| 7130010  | 30-11-2019 |                           Nintendo Switch                           |    Orinoco UK   | £329.99 |    6     | Delivered  |
| 7102000  | 02-11-2019 |                 Huawei Y6 32GB 6.09 inch Smartphone                 | DigiTec Limited | £107.50 |    2     | Delivered  |
| 6731010  | 31-07-2019 |               Numskull Multi-Format Pro Steering Wheel              |    Orinoco UK   |  £69.99 |    3     | Delivered  |
| 7304010  | 04-01-2019 |                      Canon DSLR Camera (Black)                      |    Orinoco UK   | £249.00 |    12    | Delivered  |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

1. To avoid repeating the same ID and date

   - you need to keep track of previous ID, and check for it to change the `print` based on that
2. To get a good column formatting

   - you need to specify some sizes in the format string such as `{:70s}`

```
headers = ['Order ID', 'Order Date', 'Product Description', 'Seller Name', 'Price', 'Quantity', 'Status']
print("{}\t{}\t\t{:70s}\t{:20s}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(*headers))

prev_id = ""
for order in orders:
    if prev_id == order[0]:
        print("\t\t\t\t\t{:70s}\t{:20s}\t{}\t{:>8d}\t{}".format(*order[2:]))
    else:
        print("{}\t\t{}\t\t{:70s}\t{:20s}\t{}\t{:>8d}\t{}".format(*order))
    prev_id = order[0]


Order ID        Order Date              Product Description                                                     Seller Name             Price   Quantity        Status
7306010         06-01-2020              Lenovo V145 15.6" FHD Laptop AMD A9-9425, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Black     IntelliWorld            £444.99        1        Delivered
7224010         24-12-2019              Samsung Galaxy M30s SIM Free Smartphone                                 DigiTec Limited         £249.00        4        Delivered
                                        Nikon Digital DSLR Camera Body (Black)                                  Orinoco UK              £721.00        1        Delivered
7130010         30-11-2019              Nintendo Switch                                                         Orinoco UK              £329.99        6        Delivered
7102000         02-11-2019              Huawei Y6 32GB 6.09 inch Smartphone                                     DigiTec Limited         £107.50        2        Delivered
6731010         31-07-2019              Numskull Multi-Format Pro Steering Wheel                                Orinoco UK              £69.99         3        Delivered
7304010         04-01-2019              Canon DSLR Camera (Black)                                               Orinoco UK              £249.00       12        Delivered
```

---

Using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
headers = ['Order ID', 'Order Date', 'Product Description', 'Seller Name', 'Price', 'Quantity', 'Status']
df = pd.DataFrame(orders, columns=headers)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

```
|    |   Order ID | Order Date   | Product Description                                                 | Seller Name     | Price   |   Quantity | Status    |
|---:|-----------:|:-------------|:--------------------------------------------------------------------|:----------------|:--------|-----------:|:----------|
|  0 |    7306010 | 06-01-2020   | Lenovo V145 15.6" FHD Laptop AMD A9-9425, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, Black | IntelliWorld    | £444.99 |          1 | Delivered |
|  1 |    7224010 | 24-12-2019   | Samsung Galaxy M30s SIM Free Smartphone                             | DigiTec Limited | £249.00 |          4 | Delivered |
|  2 |    7224010 | 24-12-2019   | Nikon Digital DSLR Camera Body (Black)                              | Orinoco UK      | £721.00 |          1 | Delivered |
|  3 |    7130010 | 30-11-2019   | Nintendo Switch                                                     | Orinoco UK      | £329.99 |          6 | Delivered |
|  4 |    7102000 | 02-11-2019   | Huawei Y6 32GB 6.09 inch Smartphone                                 | DigiTec Limited | £107.50 |          2 | Delivered |
|  5 |    6731010 | 31-07-2019   | Numskull Multi-Format Pro Steering Wheel                            | Orinoco UK      | £69.99  |          3 | Delivered |
|  6 |    7304010 | 04-01-2019   | Canon DSLR Camera (Black)                                           | Orinoco UK      | £249.00 |         12 | Delivered |
```

Comment: I really appreciate your attempt but for some reason it does not display order ID and order date which changes the position of next columns

Comment: @Kapol I put the code that gives exactly the images you show : when the ID and date are the same that previous row : you DON'T show them, that's what I did, and instead you accept an answer that gives markdown output, I really don't get it